# Is the shared L2 cache in multicore processors multiported?

Tags: c, multithreading, x86, multicore

In x86 multicore processors, we have a shared L2 cache. I was wondering if its multiported. For example if Core1 and Core2 both are reading the same instruction, which is not in their local L1 cache, but in L2 cache. Would both of them get that cache block loaded from L2 to L1 cache at the same time. In other words, is the shared L2 cache multiported or the accesses are serialized?

Comment: Modern multi-core x86 CPUs have shared L3 cache. L1 and L2 are usually per-core.

Comment: Any shared cache for that matter. In that case you can assume I'm talking about L3 cache.

Comment: Read about the ring layout mentioned - keep in mind that the L3 is not a single entity. Read here for more details - http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/8/